# XSS vulnerability when <c:url> and <c:param> value is injected into a JavaScript string literal

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, xss, url-encoding

My static analyzer has flagged the following XSS error.  I would like to understand if it is possible to inject malicious code into this parameter, to cause the injected value to be interpreted as JavaScript (possibly by prematurely terminating the JavaScript string literal), or to cause the injected value to redirect to somewhere other than the intended destination with a value that is refused by the server.

```
<c:url var="myUrl" value="/somepage.jsp">
  <c:param name="myParam" value="${param.userSuppliedParameter}"/>
</c:url>

<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    document.location = "${myUrl}";
  //-->
</script>
```

It is noteworthy that the server will properly handle the redirect URL in cases where the url parameter is simply altered and additional URL parameters will be ignored.  I am chiefly interested in determining if an attacker could inject executable JavaScript into **this** page using the `userSuppliedParameter` URL query param, and if it is possible for an attacker to get the document.location to be evaluated as anything other than /somepage.jsp with any arbitrary URL parameters.  For example: `http://foo.com/bar.jsp?userSuppliedParam=SOME_POTENTIALLY_MALICIOUS_PAYLOAD`. I am not concerned about values getting injected into the destination page, or the way the destination page will interpret the URL.

`<c:url>` should URL encode the URL parameters, which would prevent someone from adding an '@' symbol, which would otherwise cause preceding characters to be interpreted as basic authentication parameters.  This would otherwise expose an [open redirect vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect).

`<c:url>` should also encode double quotes, which would prevent someone from terminating the JavaScript string literal.

I am basing my assumptions about url encodings on the [RFC](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/2396/) and the JavaDoc for [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

Any other possible abuse?

Comment: Can't think of any other openings

Comment: Automated XSS checking does tend to overdo it but where are these user params coming from and when do these tags render?

Comment: Also, the html comments in the script tags thing is kind of pointless unless you really are supporting browsers that don't know what to do with a script tag.

Comment: Thanks @erik-reppen -- From a security perspective, it shouldn't matter where the user params are coming from, they're query params from the URL, and thus could be tampered with by someone posting a link somewhere, like in a phishing email or in a blog post on another site.  Perhaps it wasn't clear that these are URL query params.

Comment: That looks definitely a false warning. Try to see if `document.location = "<c:out value="${myUrl}"/>";` would tone down the static analyzer. @Erik: the `${param}` in JSP refers the HTTP request parameter map.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC.  I think your suggestion would result in the XMLEscaping of the URL value, which would convert the '&' characters in the URL to "&amp;", which would not be interpreted correctly.  Changing it to <c:out value="${myUrl}" escapeXml="false"/> still sets off alarms.  Thanks again for the suggestion -- I'm impressed by how many threads I see you helping with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consensus is that this is a false positive.  I'll update this, if I find a potential vulnerability.